# buffer vs base64 in NodeJs?

Tags: binary, base64

What is the difference between base64 and buffer in NodeJs?

Input passed within the POST body. Supported input methods: raw image binary. What does raw image binary mean - base64 or buffer?

```
 buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 77 00 00 01 b6 08 06 00 00 00 84 74 c6 ef 00 00 18 34 69 43 43 50 49 43 43 20 50 72 6f 66 69 ... 275877 more bytes>,
```

Would this work, for the input format if I passed it to the API?

Answer (score 1):

base64 is a style of storing information(where 6 bits encode your information). It's usually used for image to binary conversion (and encoding decoding).

Buffer is a storage type that uses dynamic heap and is used for ensuring conversion standards ( IPCs can be encoded in utf-8, however if you start utilizing Sockets or network packets then they will have their own encoding types).

Raw image binary means raw values. You may save them either as base64 or in the Buffer as per your convenience

Comment: What is the best way to store images in a database? In what format?

Comment: Base64 should be used for image storing. Buffer is just for temporary memory